# Conditional probability of $X$ being even given joint pmf $f_{XY}$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I want to calculate:

$$ \mathbb{P}[ 2Y = 3X ~\vert~ \text{$X$ is even} ]$$

given this joint pmf:

$$ \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y = n) = e^{-2} \frac{(1-e^{-1})^k}{(n-k)!}$$

---

From the joint I found the density of $X$ ( by summing from $n = k$ to infinity) : $$ f_X(x) = e^{-1}(1-e^{-1})^k $$
So $ X + 1 \sim \text{Geometric}(e^{-1}) $

Then I found the density of $Y$ conditional $X = x$ by dividing the joint by density of $X$,  I found the density $f_{Y \vert X = k}(n) = \frac{ e^{-1}}{(n-k)!}$, where $n \geq k$. I hope my calculations are all right until now.

But I think I messed up somewhere, because 
$$  \mathbb{P}\left[ Y = \frac{3}{2}X ~\middle|~ X = 2c \right] =  \mathbb{P}[ Y = 3c ~\vert~ X = 2c ] = \sum_{c=0}^\infty \frac{ e^{-1}}{(3c-2c)!}$$ 
adds up to one which makes no sense.

How do I find $ \mathbb{P}[ 2Y = 3X ~\vert~ \text{$X$ is even} ]$ ?

Comment: Maybe you should first check whether the conditional pmf that you specify is a valid pmf?  The probability masses are $\frac{e^-{1}}{1!}, \frac{e^-{1}}{2!}, \frac{e^{-1}}{3!}, \ldots$ which add up to $e^{-1}(e-1) < 1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have fixed that for the OP. Originally it was $n > k$ now it's inclusive $n \geq k$.

Comment: Wow, I messed up. I will be taking a closer look at this.

Comment: There's information missing: one needs the marginal pmf of $X$. Namely, one needs $f_X(k)$ for all $k = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$ where you also need to specify if $k = 0$ is included.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin. No, the pmf of $X$ is  _not_ needed to find the desired _conditional_ probability which can be found by (i) _writing out_ the first few terms of that last summation (perhaps after first noticing that $3c-2c = c$) instead of using gobbledygook like summation signs and the like, and then (ii) comparing the result to the series in my first comment above.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I added some information about how I got to this point. Still, I do not know how to calculate that probability.

Comment: Here the desired probability is scanning over the "conditions" $X = k = 2c$ (and not just scanning over $Y$ for a fixed $X$) thus knowing individual conditional pmf (given $X = k$) is not enough in that you also need the relative weight between the conditionals. That is, one needs $f_{Y|X} \cdot f_X$ , which is equivalent to the joint pmf. I have restructured the question post and cleaned it up a little bit. Hope you don't mind. Feel free to overwrite my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please load the page twice for the hyperlinks to work properly

Given the joint pmf
$$\mathbb{P}(X = k, Y = n) = e^{-2} \frac{(1-e^{-1})^k}{(n-k)!}~, \qquad n\geq k\geq 0  \label{eq_joint_pmf} \tag*{Eq.(1)}$$
where $k = 0$ and $n = k$ are explicitly included, indeed we have the marginal for $X$ as Geometric
$$f_X(k) = \frac1{e} \bigl( 1 - \frac1{e}\bigr)^k  \label{eq_x-marginal} \tag*{Eq.(2)}$$
The desired conditional probability is
$$\mathbb{P}\bigl[\, 2Y = 3X ~\vert~ \text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] = \frac{ \mathbb{P}\bigl[\, 2Y = 3X ~~\&~~\text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] }{ \mathbb{P}\bigl[\, \text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] } \label{eq_target} \tag*{Eq.(3)}$$

---

Let me assume that the event $\{ X ~\text{is even}\}$ means $X = 0,2,4,6,\ldots$ with zero included. First we obtain the denominator in \ref{eq_target} by summing \ref{eq_x-marginal} over the desired subset
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigl[\, \text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] = \sum_{c = 0}^{\infty} f_X(2c) &= \sum_{c = 0}^{\infty} \frac1{e}  \bigl( 1 - \frac1{e}\bigr)^{2c} \\
&= \frac1{e} \frac1{1 - \bigl( 1 - \frac1{e}\bigr)^2 } =\frac1{ 2 - \frac1{e} } \approx 0.6127  \label{eq_pr_x-even} \tag*{Eq.(4)}
\end{align}
First we obtain the numerator in \ref{eq_target} by summing \ref{eq_joint_pmf}, again, over the desired subset where $X = k = 2c$ and $Y = n = 3c$.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigl[\, 2Y = 3X ~~\&~~\text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] &= \sum_{c = 0}^{\infty} e^{-2} \frac{(1-e^{-1})^{2c} }{ (3c - 2c)! }  && \text{, denote $\lambda \equiv \bigl( 1 - \frac1{e} \bigr)^2$} \\
&= \frac1{ e^2 }  \sum_{c = 0}^{\infty} \frac{ \lambda^c }{ c! } && \\
&= \frac1{ e^2 } e^\lambda && \label{eq_pr_x-even_y-3} \tag*{Eq.(5a)}
\end{align}
To divide by \ref{eq_pr_x-even} one might consider rewriting \ref{eq_pr_x-even_y-3} as
$$\frac1{ e^2 } e^\lambda = \frac1{ e } \exp\left[ -1 + 1 - \frac2{e} + \frac1{ e^2} \right] = \frac1{ e } \exp\left[ \frac{-1}{e} \bigl( 2 - \frac1{e} \bigr) \right] \label{eq_pr_x-even_y-3_alt} \tag*{Eq.(5b)} $$
so that one can have a nice form for the desired conditional probability \ref{eq_target} with $\rho \equiv 2 - e^{-1}$

> $$\mathbb{P}\bigl[\, 2Y = 3X ~\vert~ \text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] = \frac{ \frac1{ e^2 } e^\lambda }{ 1/(2 - e^{-1}) } = \frac{ \rho }{ e } \exp\left[ \frac{-\rho}{e} \right] \approx 0.32938 $$

The procedure is similar if one wants to exclude zero from the set of even numbers. The result 
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}}\mathbb{P}\bigl[\, 2Y = 3X ~~\&~~\text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] \cdot \mathbb{P}\bigl[\, \text{$X$ is even} \,\bigr] ^{-1} \\
&= \frac{ \displaystyle \exp\left[ \bigl( \frac1{e} - 1 \bigr)^2 \right] -1  }{ e^2 } \cdot \left( \frac{ \displaystyle\bigl( \frac1{e} - 1 \bigr)^2 }{ 2 - e^{-1} } \right)^{-1} \approx 0.271529 
\end{align}